# Church Audio stream only setup

Tags: daw, mixer, cockos-reaper

I am part of a small congregation who worship just for a few hours in a multifunction building, setting up and packing away each Sunday.

We broadcast our service, Audio Only, over internet-radio, for a small handful of regular listeners. Recently we purchased a Teltonika RUTX50 mobile industrial 5g router, which now provides us with excellent internet, upload, and download speeds, so we decided it would be good if we were to broadcast the Audio also on YouTube through OBS just using some images for slides.

We have started doing this but have kept all the YouTube videos unlisted as we have some problems, our sound checks take too long, and the sound for the broadcast needs to be more consistent/ balanced.

We currently have a live band, including a couple of vocalists.

The FOH mixer is an old Peavey FX19, and the mix goes out the FX19 via two Auxiliary cables into a Behringer MDX2600 composer Pro XL.
Then out of the MDX2600 via two XLR leads into another smaller analogue mixer, the Yamaha MG10XU, and then sends the final mix to a PC via USB cable.

Routing Audio first into the MDX allows us to fade the main mix in and out and take Audio from the PC as an intro or end of the broadcast, controlling the total mix volume. Along with the main mix, adding crowd mics here becomes part of the main mix.

We need to control the mix-out and intro when using a DAW; how can this be done?
A digital mixer which is rack mountable may help save us time in the sound-checking process because it has preset capabilities. It also has a  mult mixi-USB output.

By sending the Audio out by USB as I have seen into a laptop with a DAW installed, such as Reaper, the audio mix for the broadcast can be more tailored and monitored, as we have seen on YouTube.

The diagram below might work with a digital mixer and DAW.

Suppose we installed a DAW on the PC and ran the mix straight from the FOH mixer into the PC. How can we separate the mix output from the DAW from any audio file we play on the PC if they are both on the PC? It is not possible to have separate audio tracks travel back into the little mixer and separate them.

The concern is that however the DAW is incorporated, how do we ensure we can control the mix through the MDX so we can play intros and end-of-service?

What would the right setup be?

In my edited version hope its more clear.

[image: mixer to daw to mixer to pc]

Comment: It doesn't make sense to me to have two computers in the signal chain, but I don't understand the scenario and motivation behind this signal chain enough to write a complete answer.

Comment: I’m confused. Are you mixing in the DAW or mixing on the mixer or both? The problem you’re having is what we really need to know and it’s unclear. The sound is “inconsistent and unbalanced”? Can you provide an audio sample? If you’re trying to send the FOH stereo mix right over the internet, that might not work because the sound that is good in the room often isn’t good for streaming outside of the room.

Comment: Hi I have added further info to my original post, than you.

Comment: I almost think it would be clearest to take out 90% of what’s in there and clearly state the *problem* and leave out any ideas you have for a solution and see if we can come up with a good solution. Asking us to validate possible solutions isn’t the best way to go because it makes the problem harder to understand and is just a simple yes or no when instead we could offer a lot more insight. If you can’t explain the problem in like two paragraphs, part of your problem might be that you yourself don’t fully understand the problem.

Comment: I was just in the middle of rewriting hoping no one would have commented let me repost now tell me what you think.

Comment: Hi Todd, sorry I'm not making my self very clear, I agree what I wrote is confusing.  Q. If the mix goes out from the FOH into a DAW to mix for the broadcast, how can we then fade in and out the mix and an intro and end of service track manually. What set up would be needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure more gear is the answer to this!    A sound check for a regular setup shouldn't take THAT long (or if it does, start it earlier!)   Is the time being taken with arguments over monitor levels?  Run the whole thing quieter, a lot of the problems will go away and the audience will love it!   And you can probably throw that compressor away.

There's a degree of truth in the idea that the FOH mix needs to be different to the broadcast feed.   In a small venue, FOH is reinforcing direct sound from the stage, not replacing it.

Try this.  For the music sections, put a stereo pair in the 'sweet spot' of the room and broadcast just that.  (What do you mean, there ISN'T a spot in the room where the music sounds good?  Sort that out, then!)   For the religious stuff, add the speakers' close mics.  Should be able to do that all on one board.

Comment: Hello Laurence, thanks for the reply. The problem is that people are normally late to set up so thats why sound checking can take too long or gets cut short. For now I will try your suggestion and lower the FOH mixer out put right down and by pass the compressor and go straight into the desk, It might take a little while to find the right level but your suggestion might well be the answer, tho I would like to see a new mixer. As for the compressor no one likes it anyhow.

Comment: @ooglespeck Why do you want a new mixer? Completely unrelated reasons?

Comment: @ooglespeck Yes, it's hard when everyone isn't acting responsibly!   So why the compressor, if no one likes it?

Comment: Hi, A new mixer.
 Well, It's the idea that it can be preset to save time, and because it sends out a multi-channel mix, it can be sent to a DAW.

I've just discovered these things, by the way.

From next week,k unless another option comes, along I will start turning way down the FOH mixer outputs and remove the compressor.

No one knows the correct setting for it tho,  we have an engineer friend, but they're hard to pin down.

Comment: Hey Laurence I don't know maybe I was not paying attention but I have now understood your suggestion.

"Try this. For the music sections, put a stereo pair in the 'sweet spot' of the room and broadcast just that. (What do you mean, there ISN'T a spot in the room where the music sounds good? Sort that out, then!) For the religious stuff, add the speakers' close mics. Should be able to do that all on one board."

Im going to suggest we do just this. No, no, it makes total sense to me, it's all clear to me now, it is only a little space and crowd mics = a total mix. Thank you so much.